# YUI dataTable row expandable/collapsible

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-datatable

Does someone have already made a script as following examples with YUI dataTable ?

Example :
http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/column-tree.html
http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html

I am looking for an example which produce same thing under YUI dataTable.

I see this example with yui dataTable (http://www.zachleat.com/web/2007/08/28/enlarging-your-yui-datatable-in-29-seconds-or-less/).
Does someone adjust this script with YUI DataTable 2.7.1 ?
Or improve this script ?

If you have any examples or links, I would be interested.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script works fine with YUI 2.7.0 : (http://www.zachleat.com/web/2007/08/28/enlarging-your-yui-datatable-in-29-seconds-or-less/).

He does what I need !

Answer (score 0):

There's a [thread on nabble](http://www.nabble.com/YUI-datatable-with-tree-like-expansion-of-records-td21172154.html) about creating a tree based datatable with YUI.